# TYPO3: Create frontend URL with mount point MP parameter

Tags: typo3, typo3-12.x

I'm in a frontend plugin controller and want to create an URL to a page with [mount point](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/12.4/en-us/ApiOverview/MountPoints/Index.html) information. How can I do that?

There does not seem to be a way to pass custom `MP` parameters to `LinkFactory::create`:

```
$linkFactory = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(LinkFactory::class);
$link = $linkFactory->create(
    '',
    [
       'parameter'        => '23',//page uid
       'forceAbsoluteUrl' => true,
    ],
    $contentObject
);
$url = $link->getUrl();
```

Example:
my page tree:

```
typo3 root
+ generic product #23
| + generic product details #24
|
+ product #42 -> mounts #23 with mount_pid_ol=1
```

I want to generate a link to "generic product details #24" in the MP context of product #42.

Comment: So far, I have no solution, but I stumbled over `config.MP_defaults`. Maybe it can point you in a good direction...